# angular js: module is not available and scope is not defined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am still relatively new to angular, I am trying to build something but I keep getting the error that module 'ngDirTest is not available', I have put it in the body tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing directives</title>
    <script src="../scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('ngDirTest', [
                //controllers
        ])
    </script>
    <script src="../scripts/populate.js"></script>
    <script src="../directive/GenericDirective.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="ngDirTest">

<div ng-controller="PopulateCtrl">
    <input type="text" generic-directive ng-model="nameone"/>
    <input type="text" generic-directive ng-model="nametwo"/>
    <input type="text" generic-directive ng-model="namethree"/>
    <input type="text" generic-directive ng-model="namefour"/>
    <input type="text" generic-directive ng-model="namefive"/>
    <input type="text" generic-directive ng-model="namesix"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I also have this controller:

```
angular.module("ngDirTest").controller('PopulateCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    //

}]);
```

I tried specifying the module at the top, but problem is I am not sure how to define controllers in here:

```
angular.module('ngDirTest', [/*controllers and other dependancies*/])
```

it also complains that scope isn't defined, which I don't understand since angular is defined at the top...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define the controllers in the module declaration, that should be used for declaring other *module* dependencies.

Try this for your module declaration:

```
angular.module('ngdirTest', []);
```

And your controller looks okay

```
angular.module("ngDirTest").controller('PopulateCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // ...
}]);
```

See [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/yunitami/2/edit) using your markup pasted above